# (JAVA) do while loop for my vending machine

Tags: java

this project i use do while loop with switch case to check the input case is not match or not. i run the code but the result not what i wanted. what i expect is if the user type the wrong case, the do while loop will loop back to the input where user need to enter the case.

here is the code

```
package vending.machine;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import static vending.machine.adddrinks.drinksList;

public class VendingMachine {
    public static void main (String []args){
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        double money;
        double total;
        double balance;

        do{
            System.out.println("\nPlease insert money:");
            money = sc.nextDouble();
            if(money < 1.2){
                System.out.println("Not enough money");
            }
        }while(money < 1.2);
        System.out.println("What drinks are you looking for");
        adddrinks.showDrinks();
        adddrinks.viewDrinks();

        System.out.print("Select: 1 or 2 or 3 or 4\n");
        int select=sc.nextInt();

        do{
            switch(select){
                case 1:{
                    total = adddrinks.drinksList.get(0).getdrinkPrice();
                    balance = money - total;
                    System.out.println("Here is your balance: " + balance);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:{
                    total = adddrinks.drinksList.get(1).getdrinkPrice();
                    balance = money - total;
                    System.out.println("Here is your balance: " + balance);
                    break;
                }
                case 3:{
                    total = adddrinks.drinksList.get(2).getdrinkPrice();
                    balance = money - total;
                    System.out.println("Here is your balance: " + balance);
                    break;
                }
                case 4:{
                    total = adddrinks.drinksList.get(3).getdrinkPrice();
                    balance = money - total;
                    System.out.println("Here is your balance: " + balance);
                    break;
                }

                default:{
                    System.out.println("Invalid");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }while(select<5);
    }
}
```

here is the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv8Am.png)

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: `System.out.print("Select: 1 or 2 or 3 or 4\n");
        int select=sc.nextInt();` needs to be in your loop

Comment: my problem is when i enter the wrong input case number, it won't loop back and ask me to input the correct case number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over your input, i was so free to improve your code a bit (sorry I do not like repetations):

```
private static void main10(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What drinks are you looking for");
    adddrinks.showDrinks();
    adddrinks.viewDrinks();
    int select = 0;
    double balance = 0;
    boolean running = true;
    while (running) {
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            select = sc.nextInt();
            if (0 < select && select <= adddrinks.drinksList.size()) {
                double price = adddrinks.drinksList.get(select - 1).getdrinkPrice();
                if (balance < price) {
                    System.out.println("Not enough money, " + select + " costs " + price);
                } else {
                    balance -= price;
                    System.out.println("You choosed " + select + " , you will find it in the dispenser");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, please retry");
            }
        } else if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            balance += sc.nextDouble();
        } else {
            String input = sc.next();
            if (input == "q") {
                running = false;
                if (0 < balance)
                    System.out.println("please don't forget your change with amount of: " + balance);
                System.out.println("Have a nice day, happy to see you again");
                break;
            } else if (input == "h") {
                System.out.println("What drinks are you looking for");
                adddrinks.showDrinks();
                adddrinks.viewDrinks();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, please retry");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Your balance is: " + balance);
        System.out.println(
                "please chouce your product (e.g 2), enter coins (e.g 2.0), click on 'h' to show product list or click on 'q' to get your change");

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the assistant at the codes. i'm just beginner at java programming.

Comment: @Noobprogrammer_69 Glad I could help, and please keep in mind, your code is not "false" as long it work, but you often can improve your code in the dimensions of maintainability and readability. The code i've posted is far from perfect code too...

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your code. When you are giving the input as 5 it is giving invalid.
After that it will go to the while statement and check the condition there. If you are inside the switch case and select any random case It will show you invalid. After that depending upon the number that you have entered.

`If the number is less than 5, It will again go to switch case.`

As it doesn't make sense as If you continue to provide correct input to it. The code will continue to execute making the **balance going in the negative**. this condition should be changed to

`while(balance>1.2)`

assuming that it is minimum amount that is necessary to buy a drink. This will check the condition after every drink and will hopefully do what you were hoping. 
On side Note : Make your code modular.